# Divide column of data by mean of the group

Tags: r, aggregate, grouping, mean, summary

If I have a data frame, such as:

```
group=rep(1:4,each=10)
data=c(seq(1,10,1),seq(5,50,5),seq(20,11,-1),seq(0.3,3,0.3))
DF=data.frame(group,data)
```

Now, I would like to divide each `data` element by the mean of its group. For example:

```
group=rep(1:4,each=10)
data=c(seq(1,10,1),seq(5,50,5),seq(20,11,-1),seq(0.3,3,0.3))
DF=data.frame(group,data)
aggregate(DF,by=list(DF$group),FUN=mean)

#Group.1 group  data
#1       1     1  5.50
#2       2     2 27.50
#3       3     3 15.50
#4       4     4  1.65

data1=c(seq(1,10,1)/5.5,seq(5,50,5)/27.5,seq(20,11,-1)/15.5,seq(0.3,3,0.3)/1.65)
DF1=data.frame(group, data1)
```

However, this is a bit convoluted, and work not work easily in a large dataset. I feel like there is an `apply` application which could be used here, but I cannot find a nice way to do it.

Comment: `DF$newdata = DF$data / ave(DF$data, DF$group, FUN = mean)` ?

Comment: I wasn't aware of `ave`. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `mean` is the default value of `FUN=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the usual set of options (thanks to @G.Grothendieck for simplification of `ave`):

```
# base R 
DF$newdata = ave(DF$data, DF$group, FUN = function(x) x/mean(x))
# or...
DF$newdata = DF$data / ave(DF$data, DF$group)

# dplyr
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(newdata = data/mean(data))

# data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, newdata := data/mean(data), by=group]
```